# No printer driver for Windows 7 - is there a way to use Vista's?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, drivers, printer

I have an Olivetti d-copia 150d multifunctional printer and I recently updated to Windows 7 on my computer, but I can't seem to find the printer's drivers for Win7.

[Their webpage](http://www.olivetti.com/Tool/Download/DriverFirmware/view_html) does have Windows Vista (and older) drivers, though. I've read that some people got their printers to work under Win7 by running the Vista drivers in compatibility mode, but that didn't work for me (it says I'm not running a compatible OS).

The only way I've found to use it so far is to install a Windows XP inside a virtual machine and, every time I need to print something, copy it to the VM and print from there. (As you can imagine, it's quite an impractical solution.)

Is there any other way around this problem? Or am I out of luck? I can't imagine Windows Vista and 7 being so different drivers-wise, and I'd really like to avoid downgrading to Vista.

Answer (score 1):

you can TRY(!) to install the vista driver manualy.

extract the driver files (do not start the setup),

Create a new printer and select the driver extraced before

but be careful - maybe your spooler service crashes and wont startup anymore - so if that happens you have to remove the printer manualy from the registry, start the spooler service and uninstall the driver under "Printserversettings"

Comment: btw: maybe the driver comes with an executeable which is extracting the driver to a specified folder - you have to execute this but do not go on with the setup

Comment: Bah, it seems the provided driver ins't even for x64, so no luck there. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of legacy devices with which I've had to use a somewhat painful, but workable solution.  I have used VirtualBox to create a VM that runs in the background, in which I have installed Windows XP.  I have installed nothing else except service packs and the drivers for my legacy devices into this VM.  I then use the setup to have the VM appear as a machine attached to my local network and share the printer with the network from the VM.

I have gotten an old Epson multifunction printer to work this way.  I haven't had as much luck with an old Pinnacle video capture card yet, but I'm still playing around with it.  It's not a great solution, but for an MFP, it works.  And I only spin up the VM when I know I'm going to need to access the printer from one of my Win7 machines.

Comment: It would be far easier to use the Windows XP mode included in most licenses of Windows 7 without the need of buying a Windows Xp license and a VMWARE license.  It likely would be cheaper also.

Comment: This setup is much better than what I'm currently using, but don't I need the printer drivers on both computers to use it over a network? How did you get it to run without the Win7 drivers?

Comment: For some reason I was never able to get XP mode to work on my primary setup.  But that is a good choice as well.